# Solving a non-linear PDE takes forever

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am trying to solve a rather, at least I think so, easy PDE but I am stuck and hope someone can help me, since I am rather unskilled in Mathematica details.

In my concrete problem I want to simulate interdiffusion of a two-species system inside a crystal. So for a start I tried to solve a simple diffusion problem with a constant diffusion coefficient. So the problem goes like this

$ \frac{d x}{d t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} D \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} $

with $D$ being constant. In my Beginner-Mathematica code this will look something like this

```
dDSim = 2*^-8
dThick := 1600*^-9
dTime = 1*^-4
eqSimple = D[x[z, t], t] == D[ dDSim*D[x[z, t], z], z]
eqIni = x[z, 0] == Piecewise[{{1*199/200, z < dThick/2}, {1*1/200, z >= dThick/2}}]
eqBLeft = Derivative[1, 0][x][0, t] == 0
eqBRight = Derivative[1, 0][x][dThick, t] == 0
mol[n_,o_]:={"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"->{"TensorProductGrid","MaxPoints"->n,"MinPoints"->n,"DifferenceOrder"->n}}
res = NDSolve[{eqSimple, eqIni, eqBLeft, eqBRight},x, {z, 0, dThick}, {t, 0, dTime},Method->mol[40,9]]

Plot3D[Evaluate[x[z, t] /. res], {t, 0, dTime}, {z, 0, dThick}, AxesLabel -> {time, thickness, x val}]
```

[image: Simulation]

When I run the NDSolve command it gives me a eerrii warning saying that the estimated initial error on the spatial grid in the direction of the independent variable z exceeds the prescribed error tolerance. Someone knows how to fix  that?

Anyway, I do not want to simulate "normal" diffusion but interdiffusion, which means that I am not left with a constant diffusion coefficient anymore. In the simplest possible case my equation for $D$ changes to 
$D\propto \frac{1}{x(z,t)} + \frac{1}{1-x(z,t)}$

( the function x in the denominator is the reason why I did not choose 1 and 0 in the initial conditions above, but fractions being close to 1 and 0, respectively ) So when I just change the first line in the above code to

```
dDSim = 2*^-8*(1/x[z, t] + 1/(1 - x[z, t]))
```

and run the whole thing, it just tries to solve the system forever and in the end seems to eat up all my RAM and my computer crashes.
I know that the problem is not that hard because I have written a code in C++ to solve the problem which works quiet well and fast. So I guess I am doing something terribly wrong. Any ideas?

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Can you show us the specific scheme you use in C++? It's not immediately clear to me how this scheme (I simply checked [its wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method)) can be used for solving your equation.

Comment: The fact that you have a C++ scheme does not say anything why `NDSolve` has problems. Also note that you specify a discontinues initial condition which is not a good model. Further more you have warning messages in the linear case too, I'd fix those before looking into the non-linear case.

Comment: Hello, ok so some additional comments. I used the numerical scheme as indicated on the wikipedia page under "Extensions to Nonlinear Problems". The flux function then is $f=-D \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$

Comment: Sorry, mixed up the first comment. so again: Hello, ok so some additional comments. @xzczd : I used the numerical scheme as indicated on the wikipedia page under "Extensions to Nonlinear Problems". The flux function I then used is $f=-D \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$ where I evaluated the derivative just by simple first-order approximation. Does that clarify my approach?

Comment: @user21 : I know that a scheme in C++ says nothing about Mathematica. Well, what do you mean by "good model"? I dont know what its supposed to mean. I will look into the warning messanges in some days since I do not have time right now. But thanks for the help so far...

Comment: Hmm… If the derivative is calculated by simple first-order approximation, the scheme will involve $z-\Delta z$, $z$, $z+\Delta z$, $z+2 \Delta z$ or  $z-2 \Delta z$, $z-\Delta z$, $z$, $z+\Delta z$, then how do you update the grid value at the grid point next to the boundary?

Comment: @xzczd I invoced a simple no-flow condition at the boundary. That is, at the left boundary it is assumed that the flow to the left is zero and at the right boundary the flow to the right is zero.

Comment: Do you mean that, suppose the grid point value is $x_1,x_2,x_3…,x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_{n}$, you've simply set $x_1=x_2=x_3$ and $x_{n-2}=x_{n-1}=x_{n}$? Also, what $\Delta z$ and $\Delta t$ do you choose?

Comment: No, I mean that for calculating $x_1$, I assumed that there is a $x_0$ for which $x_0 = x_1$ and for $x_n$ that there is a $x_{n+1}=x_n$. For $x_2$ and $x_{n-1}$ I do not have to make any assumptions I think. I then split the system into 200 equally spaced cells, giving me $\Delta z$ and chose $\Delta t$ such that the CFL condition holds.